# Is it possible to call the Razor Compiler Programmatically from a Controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using ASP .NET MVC 3 and I have an interesting problem to solve that I am hoping for some advice on.

I have a page that has a number of divs inside it.  The contents of each div changes over time and so currently I have a timer for each div running that makes a $.ajax request to the server which returns a PartialViewResult with the updated contents of the div.  The partial view is quite complex and references other views.

The problem with this approach is that it does not scale very well.  It could be that each user has a lot of these timers running and with a lot of users the server is constantly being hit.  I would rather, therefore, make a single request to the server that returns, potentially, multiple div contents so it would be:

```
div1 { some html }
div2 { some html }
```

...

Then on the client I could put each bit of HTML into the correct position on the page.

I thought that what I could do is return JSON from the server but my problem is - how do I get the HTML?  At the moment the razor compiler will run and turn my partial view cshtml files into HTML but if I am returning JSON, is it possible to programmatically call the razor compiler?

I found Razor Engine here: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ that seems to do what I want but is it possible to do it with just vanilla ASP NET MVC?

Or, given the problem, is there a better way that I could achieve my goal?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not create an Action that returns a new PartialView that renders all of those PartialViews? That way the engine is being called from the right place, i.e. the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an Action that returns a new PartialView that renders all of those PartialViews.
e.g.
an action:

```
public PartialViewResult AggregatedAction(args)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

with a view that contains:

```
@Html.Action("IndividualAction1", null)
@Html.Action("IndividualAction2", null)
@Html.Action("IndividualAction3", null)
```

See http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx for more details.

That way there is **only one request** and the rendering engine is being called from the right place, i.e. the view.

Then with the result, you can search for the various divs and replace the html in the client.

```
$('div#id1').html('div#id1',$(data));
$('div#id2').html('div#id2',$(data));
```

If the structure of your page allows it, you should use: http://api.jquery.com/load/ (as @Jorge says) to replace all of the html with one line.

```
$('div#targetDiv').load('Controller\AggregatedAction', anyData);
```

Comment: Thanks StuperUser!  Took me a few minutes to groc your answer but that will work a charm - I have a hidden div in the page that I set as the target ID for the ajax action, inside the view that is returned for the action I loop through and put each of the divs that need updating and then in Javascript move them into the right place in the success function

Comment: Excellent. You shouldn't need to move them with JS in the mark up in the hierarchy if they're positioned differently by CSS, so you can load to a "live" unhidden div and they should be updated in position.

Answer (score 3):

You could have two methods - one that returns HTML and another than returns JSON.

Or alternatively create an ActionResult that delegates to a JsonResult [if the request is an Ajax request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx), or a PartialViewResult otherwise eg:

```
public class AjaxableResult : ActionResult
{

  private readonly JsonResult _jsonResult;
  private readonly PartialViewResult _partialViewResult;

  public AjaxableResult(JsonResult jsonResult, PartialViewResult partialViewResult)
  {
    _jsonResult = jsonResult;
    _partialViewResult = _partialViewResult;
  }      

  public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  {
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
      _jsonResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
    else
    {
      _partialViewResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering, but my problem is that I want it to be a single AJAX request to the server that returns multiple HTML elements to be inserted so think of it like a collection of HTML blobs that then on the client I put into the right place on the page

Answer (score 1):

Why you just make you ajax called and instead of expect a JSON object send to the client the html with a method in your controller of `ActionResult` remember that this type return the html of the view  type like this

```
 //this if you want get the html by get
 public ActionResult Foo()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

And the client called like this

```
$.get('your controller path', parameters to the controler , function callback)
```

or

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "your controller path",
        data: parameters to the controler
        dataType: "html",
        success: your function
    });
```

Also you can load partial views, and render in a specific parts of your view with the `jquery load` which it's no more than a ajax called

Comment: "jquery load which it's no more than a ajax called type get" wrong. If you pass the data to it as a JavaScript object it will use a POST. `"The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed."` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks, but this is like what I am currently doing - I have a timer running on the client that calls a method on the controller that gets back HTML and in the success puts it in the page.  The problem is that this means that for each element on the page that needs to be updated I need to make a separate AJAX request

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. I modified my answer

Comment: The `load()` is a good shortcut, but if the structure of the html on the final doesn't allow it to be replaced in one blob then it can't be used. Although, for the OP's requirements refactoring the markup so that it can and using `load()` gives cleaner client code.

Comment: @user1039947 in that case you should consider to check your model and see if you could modify it and create's a modelView that allows to create a better view which contains all the elements that you need instead of called for each one

Comment: @Jorge thanks but what I am wondering here is if there is a way that I can avoid updating the entire page if it is that only a small part of it requires updating.

Comment: @user1039947 you should create a partial view and render in the way that I showed, in some container of your view